# Bootstrap nav Bar menu not sliding the content to down on click of button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

when I am clicking on the button the menu is shown down but the component content is not sliding down
please see below image
I have few routes here in the screenshot coupon route is the current route but the route content not at the bottom of the menu
[image]

Comment: could you share some code to understand better

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I  copypasted menu example, now on bootstrap page examples are dedicated for bootstrap 5 beta where data-toggle="dropdown" has been changed to data-bs-toggle="dropdown". Check this.